# The Boilerplate code is not completing automatically in VScode

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, web-development-server, html5boilerplate

Earlier, the boilerplate code got automatically completed after writing `<DOCTYPE html>`, but now it's not working and I've to write the boiler plate code myself every-time.
I've tried:

1. Using HTML snippets package.
2. Uninstalling packages.
3. Re-installing Vscode.
   Nothing seems to work.

[image: Now]
[image: Earlier]

Any, help is deeply appreciated.

I am all new here, so if any sort of mistake is done by me in asking or specifying the question, I apologize.

Comment: Try `!` followed by tab. I couldn't do it faster than 1 hour

Comment: Thank you, it worked. Another alternative is to use Ctrl+Space, and the clicking HTML sample.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had this problem too. You need to change your language mode to html first. Then using `!` will work.
[The location of language mode is in the bottom right corner of vs code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OkNHt.jpg)

I ended up installing [HTML5 Boilerplate extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sidthesloth.html5-boilerplate) by sidthesloth. The boilerplate was a bit more complete.

Comment: Thank you man, it helped. I tried to do a lot of stuffs for finding the solution I settled for Ctrl+Space and clicking HTML sample, it did the same thing.But finally now I understood, what went wrong. Thank You for you answer.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I found that the suggestions were turned off.
Try *Ctrl+Space* it will turn on suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Its very simple. Go to setting of visual studio and search (emmet abbreviation). scroll down to bottom and then you will find a option/setting  named (Emmet: Trigger Expansion On Tab). Turn it on. Now open blank file and type ! and then press tab your boilerplate will ready. Its 100% working.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKLJQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue but not solved you can the steps to solve this issue

1. Open vs code
2. Click settings > Command palette
3. Search for user settings
4. Go to emmet
5. at the bottom click on the checkbox the trigger expansion tab
6. done now you can use it!